# Showing Newsfeed without setup personal sites in MySite SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, my-site, newsfeed

**Background:** I have SharePoint 2013 environment where Personal Sites are disabled by turning off "Self-Service Site Creation" in Central Administration and users can see only **About Me** and **People** in their MySites.

**Question:** Is this possible to show Newsfeeds without allowing creating personal sites in MySites? Blogs, Apps etc are not required on MySites.

Is Newsfeed functionality dependent on "Self-Service Site Creation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Newsfeed and social functionality is dependent upon the creation of a MySite.

Here's a direct reference: [Plan for My Sites in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262500.aspx#planusers)

> **Plan users and user permissions**
>
> For users to create My Sites, maintain their profiles, follow people
>   and content, and use tags and notes, there are user permissions to
>   configure in the User Profile service application. Determine which of
>   the following permissions to grant to users or groups of users:
>
> **Create Personal Site**   This permission enables users to create a
>   personal site to store their documents, **newsfeed**, and followed
>   content.

Comment: Thank you very much Trevor. Can you please share Technet source on this? That would be really helpful.

Comment: Added more info the answer, including that newsfeed storage requires a Personal Site.